# update and select in one query in mysql using cron job

Tags: php, mysql, cron

Using cron job am trying to update 30dexpf field to 1 if the expiry date is exactly 30 days far from current date. Otherwise the 30dexpf is supposed to have 0 but no success.

```
$query="UPDATE user_pages SET 30dexpf=1 WHERE expiry > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 30 DAY";
```

and i also tried this but no success

```
$query="update user_pages 30dexpf = 
(case when expiry > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 30 DAY then 1 else 0 end)";
```

here is my db structure

```
| user_id |  30dexpf  |        expiry        |

|    7    |    0      |  2016-08-30 11:27:56 |
```

Comment: And the example record should get updated because it is more than 30 days from now?

Comment: it update flag to 1 but when i make changes in date to test it still returning same results 2016-09-30 11:27:56, this time 60 days 2 months left but still flag = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guessed you want to update `30dexpf` field to `1` if the expiry date is exactly 30 days far from current date. Otherwise the `30dexpf` is supposed to have `0`.

```
UPDATE user_pages
SET `30dexpf` = CASE
                WHEN (
                    DATE(expiry) = CURDATE() + INTERVAL 30 DAY
                ) THEN 1 ELSE   0 END;
```

Comment: not working in both case when condition is true or false

Comment: **Excuse me!** 30 days from today (`2016-07-30`) is `2016-08-29` not `2016-08-30`. This is July. July has 31 days.

Comment: Yes it should. By the way your question seems unclear. Better edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You need "<" (less than)
expiry (A) need to be less than current date (B) to be expired right?

but I want to add more tips

The `update` and `select` query use same where clause - you can query the result set and see whether it is the correct or not then copy the exact where clause the `update` statement

(I can't comment jurgen d's answer yet so I post here instead)

Comment: i need to flag = 1 30 days before expiry date

Comment: then use ` where expiry = current_date + interval 30 day `